# Logarithm transformation for a function in Machine Learning

Tags: logarithms, transformation, machine-learning

I was looking for a clarification on why the function (the one raised to the power of M)  was transformed to a logarithm function. I know it will be used to find p when L is maximised ( derivative of L on p ).
But what is the underlying reason for using a logarithmic function? 
What advantages does the transformation provide?

> [image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably numerical stability. It's easy to get underflow when working with small probabilities and large exponents. Also possibly efficiency, depending on whether this is a step in a larger algorithm that will run repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, one major reason is to avoid numerical problems with the floating point numbers involved (overflow/underflow). Logs transform products into sums and scale large/small numbers into more similar orders of magnitude, without changing the underlying optimization optima.

> But what is the underlying reason for using a logarithmic function?

Beyond the practical reason above, there is a theoretical reason. 
It comes from the log-likelihood of a probabilistic model being the objective for a statistical model giving rise to all sorts of natural loss functions. For instance, [under a Gaussian error assumption, the $L_2$ error is equivalent to maximizing the *log* likelihood](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10188/why-do-cost-functions-use-the-square-error). In the case of binary classification with a sigmoid output (most similar to your case), [maximizing the *log* likelihood leads to minimizing the binary cross entropy loss](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/53400/what-makes-binary-cross-entropy-a-better-choice-for-binary-classification-than-o). This loss quantity is closely related to information theory and the KL divergence, which provides additional motivation for its use. In general, maximizing (log) likelihood is well-studied and thought to endow models with [nice statistical properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation).

---

Related: [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245046/advantage-of-inputs-targets-to-be-normally-distributed/3254916#3254916).